# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality proof (but not the usual one)

Tags: inner-products

Before you downvote/vote-to-close, I am not asking for a proof of:
$$\sum^n_{i=1}a_ib_i\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2}\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1}b_i^2 } $$
Which is what EVERY link I've found assumes is the inequality (for a proof of that see: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality&oldid=692 )

---

I am reading a book that claims the **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is actually**:
$$\vert\langle x,y\rangle\vert\le\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert$$ where $\Vert x\Vert :=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$

**with the additional claim:** equality holds $\iff\ x,y$ are linearly dependent

I cannot find a proof of this claim (only proofs for the dot product inner product). My question is: what is the simplest way to prove this (I define simplest to mean "using as few definitions outside of the inner product itself as possible" - so that's not including Gramm-Schmitt orthonormalisation, for example.)

I've just found some possible answers in the links on the right (annoyingly) but fortunately I have a second, albeit softer, question:

What inequalities that are common for say $\mathbb{R}^n$ are actually based on the inner product?

(In future I will check this site first, I was targeting lecture notes and such in my search)

**Addendum:**
I want to use this on not-finite dimensional vector spaces. I've found one proof that relies on finite-ness.

Comment: I actually quite like: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204488/proof-of-cauchy-schwarz-inequality (the question that is, I don't have my complete proof yet)

Comment: [Somebody dedicated a whole book](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_index.html) to this.

Comment: Hint: $||x-y||^2=<x-y,x-y>=<x,x>-2<x,y>+<y,y>=||x||^2-2<x,y>+||y||^2$.

Comment: Some proofs of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be found here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436559/a-natural-proof-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Answer (score 27):

If I remember correctly, Cauchy proved the inequality that you don't want proven. The generalisation that you do want proven was proven later by Schwarz. So, I think that the former inequality ought to be called the Cauchy inequality. Oh well.

The proof of the (general) Cauchy-Schwarz inequality essentially comes down to orthogonally decomposing $x$ into a component parallel to $y$ and a component perpendicular to $y$, and using the fact that the perpendicular component has a non-negative square norm. That is, we start from the statement:
$$\left\|x - \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\langle y, y \rangle} y\right\|^2 \ge 0.$$
The rest is just expanding the inner product. We have,
\begin{align*}
0 &\le \left\langle x - \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\langle y, y \rangle} y, x - \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\langle y, y \rangle} y\right\rangle \\
&= \langle x, x \rangle - \frac{\overline{\langle x, y \rangle}}{\langle y, y \rangle} \langle x, y \rangle - \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\langle y, y \rangle} \langle y, x \rangle + \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\langle y, y \rangle} \frac{\overline{\langle x, y \rangle}}{\langle y, y \rangle} \langle y, y\rangle \\
&= \langle x, x \rangle - 2\frac{|\langle x, y \rangle|^2}{\langle y, y \rangle} + \frac{|\langle x, y \rangle|^2}{\langle y, y \rangle} \\
&= \langle x, x \rangle - \frac{|\langle x, y \rangle|^2}{\langle y, y \rangle}.
\end{align*}
Rearranging yields the inequality.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. You've already got my +1, you'll get the tick when I've confirmed the answer. But really thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. :-) And I really don't want to sound patronising or anything like that, but please give Chuks and the others a break. They only want to help, I promise.

Answer (score 13):

Since $\langle tx+y,tx+y\rangle\ge0$ for all $t$, $\;\;\langle x,x\rangle t^2+2\langle x,y\rangle t+\langle y, y\rangle\ge0$ for all $t$, so

$(2\langle x,y\rangle)^2-4\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle\le0\implies \langle x,y\rangle^2\le\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle=\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert^2 \lvert\lvert y\rvert\rvert^2$.

Comment: And if $x$ and $y$ are dependent, say $ax + by = 0$, then wlog we have $b\ne 0$, so $(a/b) x + y = 0$, and setting $t = a/b$, we get an equality  in this derivation; on the other hand, if they're independent, then the first $\ge$ can be replaced by $>$, so the "equality if and only if dependent" comes from a closer reading of this proof.

Comment: @JohnHughes  Thanks for your comment; I was trying to add the justification of this claim to my answer, but you already did.

Comment: It's old question but I didn't understand that point why $\Delta \le 0$? Namely why the quadratic equation has at most one real root?

Comment: @user519955  This is using the fact that there are two real roots when $\Delta>0$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\|x-y\|^2=\langle x-y,x-y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle-2\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle=\|x\|^2-2\langle x,y\rangle+\|y\|^2$.

Comment: I've removed all the comments on this answer, as they were all off-topic. If you want to discuss the general philosophies for or against certain styles of answer, go to meta or chat.

Answer (score 6):

A proof of the inequality mimicks the proof used for $\mathbf R^n$: for $\lambda\in \mathbf R$ consider the inner product:
$$\langle\lambda x-y,\lambda x-y\rangle=\lambda^2\langle x,x\rangle-2\lambda\langle x,y\rangle+\langle\mkern1mu y,y\rangle $$
This is a quadratic polynomial in $\lambda$, which is nonnegative for every $\lambda$, hence its *reduced discriminant* is $\le 0$. Now $\langle x,x\rangle=\lVert x\rVert^2$ and similarly for $y$, so:
$$\Delta'=\langle x,y\rangle^2- \langle x,x\rangle\langle\mkern1mu y,y\rangle\le0\iff\langle x,y\rangle^2\le\lVert x\rVert^2\lVert y\rVert^2\iff\lvert\langle x,y\rangle\rvert\le \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert$$
This proves the inequality.

Furthermore, if the inequality is an equality, i.e.  if $\Delta'=0$, the quadratic polynomial has a double root, which is equal to
$\lambda=\dfrac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$; in other words 
$$\Bigl\langle\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}x-y,\langle\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}x-y\Bigr\rangle=0$$

and as an inner product is a *definite positive* bilinear form, this implies 
$$y=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}x. $$
The converse (if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, the inequality is an equality) is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$||x-\beta y||^2=\langle x-\beta y,x-\beta y\rangle \ge 0 \tag 1$$

for any $\beta \in \mathscr{R}$ and any two vectors $x$ and $y$.  We find the minimum of the square of the norm in $(1)$ by setting the  derivative with respect to $\beta$ to zero.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d||x-\beta y||^2}{d\beta}&=2\beta ||y||^2-2\langle x,y \rangle\\\\
&=0\\\\
&\implies \beta =\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{||y||^2}
\end{align}$$

whereupon we immediately see that the minimum of the norm squared is

$$\min_{\beta}\left(||x-\beta y||^2\right)=||x||^2-\frac{\langle x,y \rangle^2}{||y||^2} \tag 2$$

Inasmuch as the right-hand side of $(2)$ must be non-negative, we have the desired result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\langle x,y \rangle \le ||x||\,||y||}$$

with equality if $x=\beta y$.

Comment: Normally, you're expected to receive a message on the editing. However, the editing was on the last 2-3 lines of the proof.

Comment: @Chuks  Yes, I did see it.  Just a couple of typos.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

The inequality means that the determinant 
$$\left | \begin{array}{cc}
  \langle x, x \rangle & \langle x, y \rangle \\
  \langle y, x \rangle & \langle y, y \rangle 
\end{array} \right | \ge 0$$

with equality if and only if the vectors $x$, $y$ are linearly dependent (proportional in this case).

In general, for several vectors $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_m$ we have 
$$\left | \begin{array}{ccc}
  \langle x_1, x_1 \rangle & \ldots& \langle x_1, x_m  \rangle \\
\ldots & & \ldots\\
  \langle x_m, x_1 \rangle & \ldots& \langle x_m, x_m  \rangle 
\end{array} \right | \ge 0$$
with equality if and only if the vectors $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_m$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proof (over the field of complex numbers) of the additional claim that you mentioned. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is also proven.

**Problem:** Show that for an inner product space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ 
$$|\langle x,y \rangle|=\|x\| \cdot \|y\| \quad \text{if and only if} \quad x=\lambda y, \, \text{where} \, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}.$$

**Solution:** Notice that substituting $\lambda y$ for $x$ gives us
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\langle x,y \rangle |
 & = |\langle \lambda y, y \rangle |\\
 & = |\lambda \cdot \langle y,y \rangle |\\
 & = | \lambda | \cdot \|y\| \cdot \|y\|\\
 & = \|\lambda y\| \cdot \|y\|\\
 & = \|x\| \cdot \|y\|\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Conversely, assume that $|\langle x,y \rangle|=\|x\| \cdot \|y\|$ for some $x,y \in V$. Then notice that by the property of an inner product, $\forall \, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$
$$\langle x-\lambda y, x-\lambda y \rangle \geq 0$$
Also, notice that the left side can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle x-\lambda y, x-\lambda y \rangle
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - \lambda \langle y,x \rangle - \bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle + \lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - \lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle} - \bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle + \lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - 2\text{Re} \left(\lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle}\right) +|\lambda|^2 \langle y,y \rangle\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We know that $\langle x,y \rangle = re^{i\theta}$, where $r=|\langle x,y \rangle|$ and $\theta$ is some angle. Then $\lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle}=\lambda r e^{-i\theta}$. Since this holds for all $\lambda$, Let $\lambda=te^{i \theta}$, where $t$ is any real number. Then 
$$\lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle}=te^{i \theta} re^{-i \theta}=tr \in \mathbb{R}$$
Thus, for this  $\lambda$ (where $t$ can be any real number), the above equation and equality can be combined to give us 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle x-\lambda y, x-\lambda y \rangle
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - \lambda \langle y,x \rangle - \bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle + \lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - \lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle} - \bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle + \lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - 2\text{Re} \left(\lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle}\right) +|\lambda|^2 \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle -2tr +t^2 \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & \geq 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since this expression is positive for all $t$ and since the above inequality is a quadratic function of $t$, we know that its discriminant has to be smaller or equal $0$. Thus,
$$4r^2-4 \langle x,x \rangle \cdot \langle y,y \rangle \leq 0$$
Plugging back in $|\langle x,y \rangle|$ for $r$ gives us
$$|\langle x,y \rangle|^2\leq \langle x,x \rangle \cdot \langle y,y \rangle$$
which is equivalent to 
$$|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq \|x\| \cdot \|y\|$$
which is known as the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
However, we know that $|\langle x,y \rangle|=\|x\| \cdot \|y\|$. Thus, it has to be that 
$$4r^2-4 \langle x,x \rangle \cdot \langle y,y \rangle = 0$$
But discriminant being $0$ implies that there exists $t$ such that 
$$\langle x,x \rangle -2tr +|\lambda|^2 \langle y,y \rangle=0$$
Choose that $t$. Then for $\lambda=te^{i \theta}$, where $t$ is the specific value that we just chose, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle x-\lambda y, x-\lambda y \rangle
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - \lambda \langle y,x \rangle - \bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle + \lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - \lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle} - \bar{\lambda} \langle x,y \rangle + \lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle - 2\text{Re} \left(\lambda \overline{\langle {x,y} \rangle}\right) +|\lambda|^2 \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = \langle x,x \rangle -2tr +t^2 \langle y,y \rangle\\
 & = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
But $\langle x-\lambda y, x-\lambda y \rangle=0$ implies that $x-\lambda y=0$, which in turns gives us the desired result, namely $x=\lambda y$.

Answer (score 1):

It think the usual formulations and proofs of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality *do* include statement and proof of the additional claim that equality holds if and only if the vectors are linearly dependent. For the most obvious online example consider the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof) from Wikipedia: the before-last sentence says "Moreover, if the relation '$\geq$'... is actually an equality, then... establishes a relation of linear dependence" (this assumes without mentioning the easy converse that in case of linear dependence, the inequality will be an equality; this is just a direct application of basic properties of the scalar product). Note that the mentioned proof does not assume finite dimensionality.