# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for hermitian quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sesquilinear-forms

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb C-$vector space and let $\Phi$ be a hermitian quadratic form on $V$. Assume that $\Phi$ is positive definite, i. e., $\Phi(x)>0$ for all nonzero vectors $x\in V$. Let $\varphi$ be the polar form of $\Phi$. Prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: for all $x,y\in V$ we have
$$|\varphi(x,y)|^2\le\Phi(x)\Phi(y).$$

This is my attempt:
Let $x,y\in V, t\in\mathbb C$ and $F:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ such that $F(t)=\Phi(tx+y)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
F(t)&=\Phi(tx+y)\\
&=\varphi(tx+y,tx+y)\\
&=\varphi(tx,tx)+\varphi(tx,y)+\varphi(y,tx)+\varphi(y,y)\\
&=\overline{t}t\varphi(x,x)+\overline{t}\varphi(x,y)+t\varphi(y,x)+\varphi(y,y)\\
&=|t|^2\Phi(x)+\overline{t}\varphi(x,y)+t\varphi(y,x)+\Phi(y).
\end{align*}

I think that the proof of this inequality is similar to the case of bilinear forms, but I don't know what to do. :( Help

Comment: If you can show that $\varphi(x, y)$ is an inner product, then you can use the [usual Cauchy-Schwarz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357968/cauchy-schwarz-inequality-proof-but-not-the-usual-one/) to prove this. You could also adapt my answer in the linked question; try expanding $\Phi\left(x - \frac{\varphi(x, y)}{\Phi(y)} y\right)$ and see what you get.